# Riemann-Stieltjes

Tags: calculus

[image]

I'm asked to resolve this question i got the solution but in the solution they don't take in consideration that there a discontinuity at $0$ . They just integrate using the formula , can someone explain me why  ?

thanks !

Comment: at discontinuities, you need to consider the right/left limits of your distribution.

Comment: Yes , right so at the point 0 must add (0+1000/10000 - 0) , but it's not include in the solution

Comment: Their answer is wrong and yours is right. The jump in $\Psi$ at 0 will contribute $e^{0} \times (1/10) =1/10$ to the integral.

Comment: Thanks you @KaviRamaMurthy